# Aggregate function after XMLTABLE returns empty result set

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having troubles with a query in which I use the LISTAGG() function.

I start from table **one** in this form:

```
A   B
1  a:b:e
2  c:d:f
```

Then I transform it in table **two** this form:

```
A  B
1  a
1  b
1  e
2  c
2  d
2  f
```

Using this query:

```
SELECT A,
  trim(COLUMN_VALUE) B
FROM one,
  xmltable(('"'
  || REPLACE(B, ':', '","')
  || '"'))
```

Then I perform a

```
SELECT A,
  LISTAGG(B, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B)
FROM two
GROUP BY A
```

to go back again to the form:

```
A    B
1  a,b,e
2  c,d,f
```

The problem is that in the end the query returns an empty result set:

```
A    B
```

Instead of the one I'm expecting.
Unfortunately I can't recreate my problem with a simpler query and I cannot share the original query because it contains sensitive information.

I'm hoping this might be a known problem or maybe related to the field data type. I tried to add a `TO_CHAR(B)` inside the `LISTAGG()` function but with no success.

Comment: why are you converting from one table to another just do replace

Comment: Your queries work correctly for me (although @nikhilsugandh's comment above and answer below are relevant). Something that you're not showing us is causing the problem, not any of the above. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis In my original query I just perform a join with table **two** in order to filter out some rows later and then I put it back in the original form using LISTAGG. Here I din't include this passage because I've seen that the result is the same even if I don't execute the join, resulting in the steps that I listed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hunch about possible data type issues was correct.

The function `xmltable` returns a column of type `XMLTYPE`, in my case column *B*. The aggregate function failed whenever trying to aggregate a field of that data type.

I fixed the problem by converting the `XMLTYPE` column to string obtaining this query:

```
SELECT A,
  trim((COLUMN_VALUE).getstringval()) B
FROM one,
  xmltable(('"'
  || REPLACE(B, ':', '","')
  || '"'))
```

Using this query the returned result is correct.

Many thanks to everybody who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=51a8483d5ee10015818e7a40f192a100)**

```
SELECT A,
  LISTAGG(B, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B)
FROM 
(SELECT A,
  trim(COLUMN_VALUE) B
FROM one,
  xmltable(('"'
  || REPLACE(B, ':', '","')
  || '"'))
) two GROUP BY A
```

OUTPUT:

```
A   B
1   a, b, e
2   c, d, f
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select a.*,REPLACE(a.B, ':', ',') from NS a;
```

sql fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c1e9d/2/0

Comment: My aim is not to replace the ":" with ",". The example I posted here is a simplification. Once I have my table **two** I have to filter out some rows and then put it back in the previous form. In my question I din't include this passage because I've seen that the result is the same even if I do just the steps that I listed above

Comment: @jackscorrow whats your original question then post that??